# Trying to replace values in a data frame with other values

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors, L1, and a data frame, df2. I want to take values from df2 and replace the values of L1 with these. For example, when ABCC10 of L1 says "TCGA_DD_A1EG", I want to replace this with the value, 2.193205, from row 1 (ABCC10), column 3 (TCGA.DD.A1EG). I want to do this with every value.

L1 looks like this:

```
$ABCC10
[1] "TCGA_DD_A1EG" "TCGA_FV_A3R2" "TCGA_FV_A3I0" "TCGA_DD_A1EH" "TCGA_FV_A23B"

$ACBD6
[1] "TCGA_DD_A1EH" "TCGA_DD_A3A8" "TCGA_ES_A2HT" "TCGA_DD_A1EG" "TCGA_DD_A1EB"
```

df2 looks like this:

```
       TCGA.BC.A10Q TCGA.DD.A1EB TCGA.DD.A1EG TCGA.DD.A1EH TCGA.DD.A1EI TCGA.DD.A3A6 TCGA.DD.A3A8
ABCC10     2.540764    0.4372165     2.193205     3.265756    0.6060301     2.927072    0.6799514
ACBD6      1.112432    0.4611697     1.274129     1.802985   -0.0475743     1.071064    0.4336301
       TCGA.ES.A2HT TCGA.FV.A23B TCGA.FV.A3I0 TCGA.FV.A3R2
ABCC10  -0.08129554    2.2963764     3.196518    0.8595943
ACBD6    1.76935812    0.3644397     1.392206    1.0282030
```

Comment: Mind providing your datasets by copy and pasting the output of `dput(df1)` and `duput(df2)`?

Comment: Your `df1` looks like a `list`. Are you sure it's a df?

Comment: @RuiBarradas It is a data frame comprised of lists

Comment: It looks like a `list` of `vectors`. `df1` on the other hand is a `dataframe`.

Comment: Yes, that is right actually. I took df1 from a larger data frame, but it itself is a list. @useR

Comment: I just edited the above

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be like

```
df1 = list(ABCC10 = c("TCGA_DD_A1EG", "TCGA_FV_A3R2", "TCGA_FV_A3I0", "TCGA_DD_A1EH", "TCGA_FV_A23B"),
           ACBD6 = c("TCGA_DD_A1EH", "TCGA_DD_A3A8", "TCGA_ES_A2HT", "TCGA_DD_A1EG", "TCGA_DD_A1EB"))

df2 = data.frame(TCGA.BC.A10Q = c(2.540764, 1.112432),
                 TCGA.DD.A1EB = c(0.4372165, 0.4611697),
                 TCGA.DD.A1EG = c(2.193205, 1.274129),
                 TCGA.DD.A1EH = c(3.265756, 1.802985),
                 TCGA.DD.A1EI = c(0.6060301, -0.0475743),
                 TCGA.DD.A3A6 = c(2.927072, 1.071064),
                 TCGA.DD.A3A8 = c(0.6799514, 0.4336301),
                 TCGA.ES.A2HT = c(-0.08129554, 1.76935812),
                 TCGA.FV.A23B = c(2.2963764, 0.3644397),
                 TCGA.FV.A3I0 = c(3.196518, 1.392206),
                 TCGA.FV.A3R2 = c(0.8595943, 1.0282030),
                 row.names = c('ABCC10', 'ACBD6'))

for(i in 1:length(df1)){
  for(j in 1:length(df1[[1]])){
    df1[names(df1)[i]][[1]][j] = df2[names(df1)[i],gsub("_",".",df1[names(df1)[i]][[1]][j])]
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
$ABCC10
[1] "2.193205"  "0.8595943" "3.196518"  "3.265756"  "2.2963764"

$ACBD6
[1] "1.802985"   "0.4336301"  "1.76935812" "1.274129"   "0.4611697"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @merryberry wondering if you are facing any issue with the solution as the correct answer marking is being undone?!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will do it.
First, make up some data, a `list` and a `data.frame`.

```
df1 <- list(A = letters[1:3], B = letters[5:7])

df2 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(2), b = rnorm(2), c = rnorm(2),
                  e = rnorm(2), f = rnorm(2), g = rnorm(2))
row.names(df2) <- c('A', 'B')
```

Now the code.

```
for(i in seq_along(df1)){
    x <- gsub("_", ".", df1[[i]])
    inx <- match(x, names(df2))
    df1[[i]] <- df2[i, inx]
}
df1
```

In my tests it did what you want. If it doesn't fit your real problem, just say so.

Comment: When I tried this with the data, "Error in `[.data.frame`(bla2, i, inx) : undefined columns selected" resulted @RuiBarradas

Comment: @merryberry That is because in `df1` you have underscores and in `df2` you have dots. They do not match. I can add code to take care of that. Or maybe you should do it.

Comment: @merryberry I've just edited my code with what I've said in the previous comment.

Comment: Some of the names in my df1 are repeated, but with different TCGA values. I want the code to treat these repeated names as normal, but instead it gives me NAs. Everything else works.